# Как убрать всплывающее при автокомплите окно документации в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Какая комбинация клавиш вызывает вот это окно документации в Android Studio?
[image: деловой кот]
. Или клавиша какая залипла или баг, но это окно постоянно выскакивает после нажатия Ctrl + Пробел и выскакивания подсказки. Как мне избавится от этого? В Настройках удалял назначения кнопкам вызова документации, не помогло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не кнопка залипла и вообще к хоткеям не имеет отношения. Это такая фича для удобства разработки, чтобы при автокомплите вы сразу могли почитать, что такое там оно предлагает подставить.

Для того чтобы отключить такое волшебное удобство, снимите галку с пункта, указанного на скриншоте:

[image: screenshot]

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion: Autopopup documentation in (ms)`

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен насчет Android Studio, но в оригинальной Intellij IDEA это окно вызывается сочетанием Ctrl+Q.

Comment: Удалял в настройках эту комбинацию и ещё парочку по вызовы документации, не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать "Invalidate caches and restart"

Comment: думал уже что поможет, но все равно окно появляется. Клаву что ли новую покупать или пересобрать эту. хотелось по быстрому решить проблему, видимо не выйдет(

Comment: другую клавиатуру не пробовали? может, дело в ней, действительно?